# Domino web service provider limitation

Tags: web, service, stream, lotus-domino

I'm implementing a domino web service provider, whose purpose is to stream from the base64 format, which in the client that consumes the web service is an attachment file, transform it back into a file. In the web service provider that is developed in java, I use the Stream class and the Mime classes to, to convert the stream and file. The web service provider works well for files up to 5 MB, for larger files the error as [technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1LO58902) is displayed. Has anyone had this problem yet? Is there any way around it?

Here is the code for the web service provider

```
public class criaAnexo {
private Vector itemsToRecycle;
public void attachDocument( byte[] is) {

    // creating the output stream used to create the MIME attachments
    try
    {

        itemsToRecycle = new Vector(); 
        Session session = NotesFactory.createSession();
        Database db = session.getDatabase("Serverx", "base.nsf");
        if (!db.isOpen())
            System.out.println("names2.nsf does not exist on snapper");
        else
        {
            Stream outStream = session.createStream();
            outStream.write(is);


            session.setConvertMIME(false);

            // create the MIME body
            Document doc = db.createDocument();
            doc.replaceItemValue("Form", "formAttachment");
            MIMEEntity body = doc.createMIMEEntity();


            // create a child for each attachment<br/>
            MIMEEntity child = body.createChildEntity();

            // find the fileSuffix<br/>
            //String fileSuffix = files[i].substring(files[i].lastIndexOf(".")+1);
            String fileSuffix = "pdf";


            // set the child to the outstream using a mapped MIME type<br/>
            // MIME type mapping see: http://www.w3schools.com/media/media_mimeref.asp

            //child.setContentFromBytes(outStream, mapMIMEType(fileSuffix), MIMEEntity.ENC_IDENTITY_BINARY);

            child.setContentFromBytes(outStream, "application/pdf", MIMEEntity.ENC_IDENTITY_BINARY);


            // set name for file attachment<br/>
            MIMEHeader header = child.createHeader("Content-Disposition");
            header.setHeaderVal("attachment; filename=\"teste.pdf\"");

            // set unique id for file attachment to be able to refer to it<br/>
            header = child.createHeader("Content-ID");
            header.setHeaderVal("teste.pdf");

            //outStream.truncate();
            //outStream.close();
            outStream.close();
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime(); 
            long total_mem = rt.totalMemory(); 
            long free_mem = rt.freeMemory(); 
            long used_mem = total_mem - free_mem; 
            System.out.println("Total de Memória:"+total_mem); 
            System.out.println("Total de Memória livre:"+free_mem);
            System.out.println("Total de memoria usada pelo agente: " + used_mem/1048576);  


            doc.save( true, true );
            itemsToRecycle.add(doc);
            session.recycle(itemsToRecycle); //recycle all items added to vector 
            session.recycle();

        }



    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Have you looked at the 'Maximum size of request content' setting in your Domino server's Server Doc, and the 'Maximum POST data' setting in the appropriate Web Site Configuration Document? See here for a description: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSKTMJ_8.5.3/com.ibm.help.domino.admin85.doc/H_RESTRICTING_THE_AMOUNT_OF_DATA_USERS_CAN_SEND_TO_THE_SERVER_STEPS.html

Comment: Both parameters are set to 10 MB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact the limitation occurs in the client that consumes the web service that I implemented in the domino itself. The technote quoted in the description of the problem, implies that the problem is on the side of the provider, but in fact it is not. When I implemented the web service client on dot net the file was streamed without problems.

Comment: Complementing only happens the problem if you implement the client to consume the web service in lotusscript. In Java the problem does not happen.

Answer (score 0):

Due to base64 encoding and other overhead, files larger than 5 MB may be exceeding the 10 MB limits you have configured for the **Maximum size of request content** and **Maximum POST data** settings for your server. Try increasing them.

Comment: I increased both parameters to 50 MB and the error persists.

Comment: Did you restart the server's http task? I'm not sure if that's needed, but it might be.

Comment: Yes, I restarted the entire Domino.

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas.